# e-TeX \hbox to size of glue

Tags: pdftex, boxes, plain-tex, glue

I have a piece of glue (`\hskip 2.4in plus 2fil` specifically) that's flexible, and I want to create an `\hbox` to the same length, but `\hbox to 2.4in plus 2fil` doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve a similar result?

The reason I want to use this is to make a 3-column format with boxed in columns more flexible (especially to differently sized columns). I'm using pdfTeX, so I can use e-TeX's extra features if that's helpful

Comment: Boxes are not stretchable.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a way to get a similar result, or will I have to do the calculation "by hand?"

Comment: The final size of the `fil` glue will only be known, once the paragraph is built, i.e. you can set the width of the `\hbox` to the width of the glue, if they are in different paragraphs. (However, I don't know whether you can get the size of the glue within TeX, but it's definitely possible in Lua)

Comment: That said, if you are trying to balance columns, Appendix D of the TeXbook has an algorithm for column balancing, but it involves a loop that retypesets the columns at different width until an optimum is reached or the number of tries is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdftex features to record the position before and after a glue node, and then (on the second run) use that information to construct a box of the desired size.

Here paragraph 1 just has glue, paragraph 2 has a box with Z...Z set to the same size.

[image]

```
\newwrite\zz % easier in latex where this is set up already
\openin\zz=\jobname.aux
\ifeof\zz\else
\input \jobname.aux
\closein\zz
\fi
\immediate\openout\zz=\jobname.aux

1) zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z
zzzz%
\hskip 2.4in plus 2fil
zzz zzzz zzz
zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z
zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z

2) zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z
zzzz%
\ifx\zzA\undefined\else
\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \dimexpr \zzB sp -\zzA sp{Z\dotfill Z}}%
\pdfsavepos\write\zz{\gdef\string\zzA{\the\pdflastxpos}}%
\hskip 2.4in plus 2fil
\pdfsavepos\write\zz{\gdef\string\zzB{\the\pdflastxpos}}%
zzz zzzz zzz
zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z
zzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zzzz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz z

\bye
```

Comment: @HoldenRohrer: It is not clear, in your question, if you are using plain teX, LaTeX, or if you are looking for a “generic” solution; if you happen to be using LaTeX, I suggest you also have a look to the `savepos` module of the `zref` package.

Comment: @GuM the OP tagged it plain-tex so I went with that (although tagging isn't always to be believed, I agree:-)

Comment: Please believe that I was not criticizing your answer, but simply trying to be helpful to the OP. :-)